# Copying text file

Tags: vb6

How to copy the text file through vb6 code.

Having Source filename like clock.fin, time.mis, date.fin, so on...,

Having Destination Filename are saving in stroutput.

Stroutput as a string.

I want to give as clock.txt, time.txt, date.txt through code.

```
FileCopy App.Path & "\Temp\" & Name, App.Path & "\Temp\" & strOutput.txt
```

Getting error as Invalid qulifier in stroutput.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for one thing, the `.txt` part should be in quotes since it is a string literal.

Comment: +1. I would also say, use Option Explicit to avoid these problems in future.